# Store website not in database but in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, synchronization, server-side

Could you recommend me a nice technology for my problem? I had a blog and now it as a classical dynamic page MySql + Php + Javascript. But i would rewrite it. If an user event happend, i.e. a user posted a comment, i wouldn't store it in database, but store the changes in an HTML file. So the logic is not in the php file but in html file. How can i do that, but in an easy way.

Comment: What is the aim of it? Database is sophisticated system allowing you do more just store data - for example search ability.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want? Are you looking to store each comment in its own HTML file or edit the original one, adding the new comment in the correct place? Either way, you are going to need some logic on the server-side to do anything useful, either PHP or another technology. It might be useful to know *why* you want this, and why the current approach isn't working for you...?

Comment: Huh? you want to turn a MYSQL DB + PHP site into PHP + FLAT FILE? WHY!?

Comment: The aim? Traditional concept is too complicate. I imagine an client side solution. If i need an extra function, button, image, bullet list in HTML i can insert it with hands rather to suck with logic. On the server-side I need only a saving / storing / serializing mechanism.

Comment: No db, no search, insert by hand, store on server.... kinda reminds me of the good ol' days when updating a website means hacking at HTML then doing an FTP PUT. Hmmm...

Comment: FTP solution sound good :-) and one of my motivation is this, to be able to do some modification on HTML with FTP also. But the visitors will not add comments via FTP, so it will be need some web based interface also, nice textareas, javascript events etc.

Comment: @Kukoda You can't do this, nor do you want to. You need some server-side processing to accept comments and to dynamically generate the HTML required to display comments. What you are talking about is impossible, and not at all desirable from a maintainability stand point.

Comment: Dear meagar, i know, that i need some server-side processing, as i have written i would use it for saving / storing / serializing the HTML, but only for this porpuse, rather most part of the logic would in client side.

Comment: HTML is a document format, not a database. Use a real database for this, databases solve lots of problems that you'll have if you try to write directly to flat files.

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically parse the static html file after a user event (i.e.: POST) and append the result to the html, write back to the file, however I wouldn't recommend it as the script would have to be fairly complex to handle the html correctly.

Comment: Have a look at [Pelican](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.1.1/), which is a static site generator written in Python. [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/category/site-news.html) is a great example for a site built with it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to edit static HTML files when the user posts a comment than it is a bad approach IMHO. How would you implement searching, for example?

Don't try replicating what database is doing, because the guys that wrote database spend their whole lives doing just that.

You might want to search for existing blog solutions instead of writing one from scratch. There are many open-source projects written in many languages / platforms.

Comment: I dont want implement any searching. It would be only a blog, where you can add comments, edit your comments, add posts. So really problem is, the traditional concept is not enough flexible. i.e. If i want only one picture attach to one of my post, i need to change database design, event handling, view. It is too much complicated. I cant customize it with hand, i can do modification only in the logic. Do you understand, what i mean?

Comment: I am looking for some kind of http server that can do the same what i do in an javascript event handler, but not on the DOM structure in client side, rather on the server side's HTML file. i.e. if i add an comment field in the client side, with an button event, i would change the server side's HTML file also.

Comment: If you had such a thing and wanted it all client-side, you would need some method of saving. You would essentially be opening up your entire site to be edited by anyone. Sounds like a terrible idea. If running a PHP/MySQL site is too complex, go and sign up for a free Wordpress blog instead. Then you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Hey! I don't need to open it up for anyone. PHP scripts will do the modification, so it happen not direct, but indirect. PHP will not write into database but modify the HTML. Fortunately in PHP the DOM modifier functions are very similar to JavaScript. I need almost only copy the client side JS commands to PHP.

Comment: @Kukoda - What everyone is trying to say here is that's a bad design and a bad approach. Just don't do it. It will cause you more problems and isn't a solution to your problem. You're trying to reinvent the wheel despite the fact that you're not building a car in the first place. You should ask yourself the question that many of us are asking: what is the aim of it?

Comment: You can store HTML in database without any problems - it's just a string after all. Images will have to be stored as blobs in db or in the file system. Again, you might want to read a bit about web based applications and their architecture or just use existing blog app.